# how many distinct n-element sets can be made out of an m-element superset; n<m

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose I have a (super-)set of elements $m$ distinguishable elements. How many $n$-element subsets can be constructed? $m$ and $n$ are positive integers, and $m>n$.

Comment: @peterwhy no, let me fix up the writing. I mean the superset has $m$ distinguishable elements and I want to know how many $n$ element subsets can be made from that: say there are 18 kids in class, how many groups of exactly 5 can I make.

Comment: $\binom { m } { n }$.

Comment: In case you are not familiar and need to Google it, what @peterwhy mentions is called binomial coefficient. It is exactly what you ask for.

Comment: @peterwhy yes, I guess this is a duplicate, thanks and sorry.